# getting error in libchart library in php

Tags: php, mysql

i want to draw a piechart in php using mysql. i am getting error only for below code.

```
<?php include "libchart/classes/libchart.php"; ?>
```

during run i am getting below error. anyone please help me.

> Warning: include(libchart/classes/libchart.php) [function.include]:
>   failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\g2.php on line 2
>
> Warning: include() [function.include]: Failed opening
>   'libchart/classes/libchart.php' for inclusion
>   (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\g2.php on line
>   2

Answer (score 0):

It means the file `C:\xampp\htdocs\libchart\classes\libchart.php` does not exist

Answer (score 0):

it seems you giving wrong path for file. I think you should tell your directory path too here i.e where is the file in which you including the file and the file path which you want to include.